# Podman equivalent to Docker Compose environment variable substitution

Tags: podman

In Docker Compose we can do something such as the following to insert environment variables in a Docker Compose file:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  example-service:
    image: busybox:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    scale: ${REPLICAS:-1}
    command: ls
```

This is a great feature for running (integration) test matrices and the like, because you could simply test multiple images, replicas, etc.

As we're moving with such tests to Podman, we would also like to replace the compose files by Deployment definitions and `docker-compose` by `podman play kube`. Hence, the question is: Can we do something similar with Podman?

[This answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/1060501) proposed ConfigMaps as an option, but that only works for exposing environment variables into a pod container. It does not work for using an environment variable to create a pod.

Please note that moving to [podman-compose](https://github.com/containers/podman-compose) would be an option, but not really what we want to do. Kubernetes resource are way more powerful and seem to be the "official way".

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can use bash shell expansion:

```sh
IMAGE_TAG="v0.0.0"
printf "
version: '2.2'
services:
  example-service:
    image: busybox:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    scale: ${REPLICAS:-1}
    command: ls
"
```

Yields:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  example-service:
    image: busybox:v0.0.0
    scale: 1
    command: ls
```

`kubectl` (!) supports piping stdin directly (and `podman` may too), so you can in theory (though it's nearly always better to persist the output to a file so that you can commit a record of what you apply):

```sh
IMAGE_TAG="v0.0.0"
printf "
version: '2.2'
services:
  example-service:
    image: busybox:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    scale: ${REPLICAS:-1}
    command: ls
" \
| kubectl apply --filename=-
```

I have begun using [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to template my YAML files but previous simply used `sed`. Using the former, you can use a YAML query syntax to path to values that you want to replace and, with `sed`, of course, regular expressions.

Helm and other (Kubernetes) tools use Go templating to solve a similar problem and it remains something of an outstanding issue (unless you're happy to adopt *nix's philosophy of having tools that do one thing well)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it doesn't sufficiently answer the question. Yes, we could use shell expansion, but in contrast to the Docker Compose file, having placeholders/shell variables inside the YAML makes it an invalid Kubernetes file. That means such a file can not be used directly with Kubernetes/podman anymore and also linters, IDEs, etc. will complain about it. I'm wondering how (or if at all) podman intends to solve this use case as they basically say `podman play kube` is podmans replacement for Docker Compose.

Comment: Using yd to replace parts of the file would be a solution to preserve the original, valid YAML file, but this again involves some scripting and requires to keep the YAML file and the yd script in-sync.

Comment: Then I recommend you consider filing a feature request against podman: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues